# React-Navigation custom TabNavigation component hides header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-router, react-navigation

**TLDR:** Can i customise the view passed to *const TabNav = TabNavigator({});*, or is there a way to display the headers of nested stack navigators when the tab navigator is created with *createNavigationContainer(createNavigator(CustomTabRouter)(CustomTabView));*

I'm trying to build a custom view component that replaces the standard tab bar view (based on a floating action button).

I've looked at the StacksInTabs example which works great, but i don't see a way to customise the tabview.

When following the CustomTabs example in the docs i can't get the nested StackNavigator to display the header.

Something is definitely different when you create the TabNavigator manually by passing a router object and a view object to createNavigationContainer, but i can't work out what.

Here's a couple of samples on rnplay.org:

Using the default nav creation functions: https://rnplay.org/apps/n0ixXw
Composing my own Tab Navigator: https://rnplay.org/apps/tzTecA

They don't run on the site due to requiring outside module imports, but here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "SampleApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.41.0",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.0.22",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```